# Lenovo Thinkpad T540p recovery from sd card?

Tags: usb, thinkpad, system-restore, micro-sd-card, factory-defaults

I have a Thinkpad T540p which has to be restored to factory status.
I have tried to invoke the recovery program by pussing F11 a lot during booting when the Thinkpad logo is shown. But all I get is the windows screen saying "Windows could not be started properly. What do you want to do?" and then showing the regular options like 'boot with last known working configuration' and 'start windows normally' or 'start safe mode'.

I have tried that many times and after that I concluded that the recovery program cannot be started that way.

I then moved unto option 2: in the configuration panel, there is an option 'Lenovo recovery media'. I tried to create the recovery media on an usb stick but my stick(s) do not have enough capacity for the recovery media.

I also had a (micro) sd card which was unused and has 64gb capacity. Enough I guessed so I used that sd card to create the recovery media.
I finished creating the recovery media successfully and rebooted. But when I was in the boot menu to chose the correct boot device, the SD card is not listed in the boot devices. My regular 2gb usb pendrive is there, as is the dvd player. I already tried to boot with bootmanagers like Plop to see if it enables me to boot from the sd card (inserted in the internal sd card reader)

So right now, I have the recovery media on an SD card but I cannot use it and the lenovo recovery media program allows me only to create 1 set of recovery media so creating a new set on a regular usb pendrive cannot be done that way.

I am therefore wondering: how can I start the recovery program for this lenovo to have it back how it left the factory? Is there anyway I can make this 540p thinkpad notebook boot from sd card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to boot from the sd card using my own usb card reader and booting with ultimate boot cd. I then started Plop boot manager and it was able to boot from the sdcard then.

(the sdcard reader was recognized by the bios, but booting from the sdcard directly from bios did not work)